# How to get Contents of file into a list dict using Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, file, testing, automation, robotframework

```
File has below contents :

|Organization|ID|Name|City|Country|
|abc corp|2623883|Jane Anderson|London|England|
|abc corp|9009883|Paul Polom|Warsaw|Poland|
|rcb corp|9001883|Martina Early|Helsinki|Finlands|
```

And here is the code that I have written:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem
Library     String
Library     Collections
Library     utils.py

*** Variables ***
${file_path}=   Samplefile.txt
@{sample_list}=    900982283

*** Test Cases ***
Check given ID is not present in the text file
    Search for ID in the text file
    # Given ID should not be found in the file


*** Keywords ***
Search for ID in the text file
    &{myDict}=  Create Dictionary   
    ${allLines}=    Create List
    ${file}=    Get file    ${file_path} 
    @{lines_in_file}=   Split to lines  ${file}
    ${file_size}=   Get Length  ${lines_in_file}
    ${line0}=    Split String      ${lines_in_file}[0]    |
    Remove From List    ${lines_in_file}    0
    FOR     ${lines}    IN      @{lines_in_file}
        ${line}=    Split String    ${lines}    | 
             FOR    ${item}     IN      @{line0}
                FOR     ${value}    IN      @{line}
                    Set To Dictionary   ${myDict}   ${item}=${value}
                    Remove Values From List     ${line}     ${value}
                    Exit For Loop
                END    
                
             END
             Log To Console  ${myDict}
    END
```

Output : I am just getting 3 separate dictionaries and not a list dict

{'': '', 'Organization': 'abc corp', 'ID': '2623883', 'Name': 'Jane Anderson', 'City': 'London', 'Country': 'England'}
{'': '', 'Organization': 'abc corp', 'ID': '9009883', 'Name': 'Paul Polom', 'City': 'Warsaw', 'Country': 'Poland'}
{'': '', 'Organization': 'rcb corp', 'ID': '9001883', 'Name': 'Martina Early', 'City': 'Helsinki', 'Country': 'Finland'}

Any help or idea would be appreciated. I expect the output to be in the below format :

[{'': '', 'Organization': 'abc corp', 'ID': '2623883', 'Name': 'Jane Anderson', 'City': 'London', 'Country': 'England'},
{'': '', 'Organization': 'abc corp', 'ID': '9009883', 'Name': 'Paul Polom', 'City': 'Warsaw', 'Country': 'Poland'},
{'': '', 'Organization': 'rcb corp', 'ID': '9001883', 'Name': 'Martina Early', 'City': 'Helsinki', 'Country': 'Finland'}]

Request you to please ignore test case and keyword name.

Comment: This would be a bit easier in python. Are you open to suggestions using python or are you specifically looking for a solution using only robot keywords?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley,  I am open to using python.. Could you please guide me with the solution?